# How can i switch windows in vscode quickly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just find it is very hard to switch windows.Is there any tool or key-Binding ?

I already find some material on vscode site.

Comment: In preferences > key binds you can search and assign key bindings for this. Potentially check there, not sure what it would be called but the list isn't huge.

Comment: i find one called switch windows , but it can not force on terminal or sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

Each window has his own shortcut key, you cant use to switch windows using only one key. You can use their predefined keys to switch between windows.

Probably the most common are:

switching to the sidebar `Ctrl + b`

Selecting files in sidebar `Ctrl + Shift + e`

switch to terminal Ctrl + `

Opening the folder `Ctrl + K O`

Switching to files `Ctrl + 1` for first file `Ctrl + 2` for second and so on

You can find complete keybinding for VS Code here: [windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) [linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf) [macos](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf) ([main documentation source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference))